# Работа с ASM в FPC

Tags: pascal, ассемблер

Есть ассемблер код для Borland Turbo Pascal:

```
procedure cursOFF; Assembler;
asm
    mov ah,01;
    mov cx,$2000;
    int 10h;
end;
procedure cursON; Assembler;
asm
    mov ah,01;
    mov cx,$0fff;
    int 10h;
end;
```

Эти процедуры используются для скрытия и показа курсора. При попытке компиляции программы, которая использует вышеприведенный код, в компиляторе FreePascal – возникает куча ошибок. Как я понял, для внедрения кода asm в FreePascal используются некоторые особенности. Помогите адаптировать код для работы в FreePascal.

Пы.Сы.: Сори что беспокою столь древним программированием, решить задачу оч. нуна.

Comment: Прописываю: <pre><code>{$ASMMODE intel}</code></pre> и комплиться норм, но при вызове процедуры выходит с кодом ошибки 216.

Comment: ASM - это не древнее программирование! ASM - всегда актуален. Даже если Вы решаете задачу для 8086 совместимого процессора...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации (http://freepascal.ru/article/freepascal/20050418171713/) Вам и нужно писать {$ASMMODE intel} т.к. по умолчанию используется AT&T синтаксис как в GNU Assembler. Попробуйте заменить intel на direct. Вот описание (оттуда же):

•DIRECT — означает, что asm-вставка будет напрямую копироваться в промежуточный asm-код. Данный вариант может быть полезен при использовании совместно с директивой {$OUTPUT_FORMAT ...}, дабы во вставке использовать все возможности внешнего ассемблера.

еще гляньте сюда

```
01H уст. размер/форму курсора (текст). курсор, если он видим, всегда мерцает.
    вход:  CH = начальная строка (0-1fH; 20H=подавить курсор)
           CL = конечная строка (0-1fH)          <---------------------------
```

Возможно проблема в этом.

Comment: т.е. замените mov cx,$0fff; на mov cx,$001f;

Comment: На режим DIRECT ругается компилятор: Illegal assembler style specified "DIRECT".<br> Замена mov cx,$0fff; на mov cx,$001f; при режиме intel не помогает. Получаем exitcode 216...<br/>
Все-равно большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: попробуйте сохранить используемые регистры и по окончании процедуры восстановить их... push ax; push cx; ...; int 10h; pop cx; pop ax либо ВСЕ регистры - pusha ... popa

Comment: Неа, не помогло..

Comment: В общем, установил я FreePascal... Проверил код. Проблема: Вы, по-видимому, так же как и я, используете Win32 компилятор и Compile Target у Вас Win32. По результатам трассировки все падает на вызове int 10h (Segmentation Fault). Скорее всего, это связано с попыткой вызова прерывания BIOS из Защищенного режима процессора... Необходимо компилировать программу для DOS и запускать соответственно. Как то сделать в FreePascal я не знаю :( - попытался установить FreePascal для GO32 DOS ext - не компилирует... :(

Comment: Получилось! Удалите FreePascal для Win32 и установите FreePascal для GO32 DOS (что-то в этом роде). Компилируйте Вашу программу в нем с Compile -> Target = GO32 DOS...

Проверил - Все работает. WinXP SP3